# Marking the 666th favorite resulted in an error

Tags: status-norepro, bug

I just now added a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there) to my favorites and just as I clicked the star a small orange box showed up saying an error has occurred and I should click again. Then I realized that it had incremented the favorite counter to 666.

Has anyone else experienced this or has someone access to check what happened? Maybe there is some hidden feature behind 666 favorites? :)

UPDATE:
At least I think 666 could have given an opportunity for something planned to happen.

Comment: That was funny SO!

Comment: `status-coincidence`

Answer (score 2):

I often get ajax errors, I don't think there's anything special about that number. I don't think the team added a special error ([it isn't even a power of 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%28666%29)), nor do I believe a demon or another fantastic creature interfered with your communication at that point, awaken by its number.

Don't feel bad though; It is human to see patterns where there aren't any.

Comment: It almost sounds like you accept getting errors ;) I haven't experienced any other errors here in SO and this one was too much of a coincidence due to 666. In any case maybe someone is interested to have a look what caused the error and correct things.

Comment: I don't know - if I had to impose an arbitrary limit on something then I'd probably choose a nice round number.
At least it would be easy to spot - just search the codebase for 666! :)

Comment: @murrekatt: Errors are inevitable, even if *your* part of the system is perfect. In this age of WiFi and 3G, a failed AJAX call could mean "no route to host" - it's sometimes easier to leave the decision to retry up to the user.

Comment: @Piskvor: sure. I was not referring to that.

Comment: so what you're saying is that this is a particularly clever new kind of CAPTCHA?